# Can't seem to find the problem for the following error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list (at [FileName])"

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I am programming an ASP.NET web application. I have a button with an `onclick` event that triggers a Javascript function with a few parameters.

When I click on the button the following error gets thrown in the browser console:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list (at BusinessUnit?buLeaderId=18:212:176)

When I click on the link after "at" it marks this part of the code:

```
<a id="@employee.Id" class="col-2 btn btn-success" 
   onclick="NewAdGroupDeletionRecord(@adGroup.Name, @employee.FirstName @employee.LastName, false)">
   <i class="bi bi-check"></i>
</a>
```

I can't seem to find anything wrong with it, especially considering that there is a closing bracket after the parameters.

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<table id="DataTable" class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr style="text-align: left;">
                    <th>AD Gruppe</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var adGroup in employee.AdGroups)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <th style="text-align: left;">@adGroup.Name</th>
                        <th>
                            <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
                                <a id="@employee.Id" class="col-2 btn btn-success" onclick="NewAdGroupDeletionRecord(@adGroup.Name, @employee.FirstName @employee.LastName, false)">
                                    <i class="bi bi-check"></i>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

JS:

```
<script>
    function NewAdGroupDeletionRecord(adGroupName, employeeName, canDelete){
        console.log(adGroupName);
        console.log(employeeName);
        console.log(canDelete);
    }
</script>
```

Thanks in advance for anyone who takes the time to look at my question.

Comment: `@employee.FirstName @employee.LastName` - this looks like an issue to me. Does it need to be quoted for it to be treated as string by javascript ?

Comment: yes it turns out the space inbetween was the problem. Ill just have to Join them into a string with c# and use the string as a parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was here: `@employee.FirstName @employee.LastName`

Adding the lastname as a sepperate parameter fixed the problem.

Edit: also '' has to be added to around each parameter that you want to be treatet as a string.